# Darlington transistor heats up : regulating transformer output

Tags: power, voltage-regulator, darlington

I am in great need of a `12v` DC transformer. So I built one using some components I have lying around: the case of the transformer I have says `220 to 12V` (which I don't trust because the voltage on the first smoothing cap is `~27V` with no load/small load. The real `DC` voltage should have been `12/1.4 = 8.5`).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2feUz0v.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I am still testing this circuit and it almost works.

1. Boths caps used are `1000uF`
2. R1 is actually a cap but I set it at `2k` (max is 5k). This just sets the current on the diodes as the transistors uses very little of the current.
3. The transformer regulator is made with 18 diodes in series which drop `~12V`. I don't have a `Zener`.
4. `U1` is a 5v regulator `MC78M05BDTR`. It can take up to 500mA which is enough for the `attiny85` and the `two 7 segments displays` (they are not always on) [Datasheet](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/MC78M00-D.PDF)
5. `BD679` is a component I had at hand. [Datasheet](https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/21996/STMICROELECTRONICS/BD679.html). `Ic(max) = 4A` (way more than what the circuit draws). `Ib(max)=100mA`
6. My digispark circuit is blinking at around `2Hz` two 7 segment display. 
   As measured between `Vout` of the transformer regulator and `U1`, it draws :

   - `157mA(max)` at `9.6V`(when displays are on).  `16V` on `C1`
   - `20mA(min)` at `10.6V`(when displays are off). `24.7V` on `C1`
   - Thus the maximum power is around `1.5W(max)` and `200mW(min)`. The collector current is `~` the emitter one so I used that value when I calculated the transistor's power.

**Tests with different loads:**

- `1K` load:      `10.81V`  `9.13mA`   `26V` on `C1`
- `100ohm` load   `10.16V`  `101.4mA`  `19.26V` on `C1`
- In these cases it works perfectly and it doesn't heat up.

The problem is that after approximately 20 seconds the `regulator transistor BD679` starts to heat up and....cool down...and heat up...  Weird enough without the output filtering capacitor `C2` it takes longer to heat up. The problem seems to be connected to the frequency at which I power the displays.

But I still can't figure it out: why does it heat up? Is it because of wrong wiring(and then I should fix it) or just because too much power is drawn from it (in this case it's normal to heat up).

Comment: What is the thermal resistance of the heatsink you  are using? What power are you dissipating in the transistor? What temperature rise does that power * the heatsink's thermal resistance give you? Is it getting hotter than that temperature prediction?

Comment: No heatsink. I didn't check the CE drop. Looking into it. I chose that darlington transistor because I figured it's big enough to handle it. My circuit doesn't use that much power. Or does it?

Comment: Datasheet will tell you thermal resistance to air (no heatsink). Multiply that by 157mA * VCE=(27-11 = 16V) to get 2.5W. Datasheet says 100C/Watt (no heatsink).Put those together and ...

Comment: I get it that the only fault of my circuit is the power dissipation and not some other problem like driving the transistor in saturation or ..sth. worse

Comment: Why is C1 at 27 V?

Comment: You tell me, that's what it says on the schematic.

Comment: Is that transformer center-tapped?  Is it really a 220:12-0-12?

Comment: I took it from a washing machine. It is completly encased in plastic and it has only 4 pins. It was also connected to a half bridge. So I think it was meant to provide some 24V and then halfed by the bridge.